# Connecting to my UHF RFID reader via the provided SDK

Tags: c++, c, sdk, rfid

I'm working on a project where, I need to write my own software to use our UHF RFID reader(sports event tracking). The provided SDK is poorly documented and I have some problems.

The functions:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int OpenComm(HANDLE *hCom,char *com_port);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CloseComm(HANDLE comm);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int InitializeTag(HANDLE comm);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TagIdentify(HANDLE comm,unsigned char *recieve);//EPC��ǩʶ��
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ReadSoftwareVersion(HANDLE comm,char *receive);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int StopWorkSetting(HANDLE comm);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TagRead(HANDLE comm,int length,unsigned char membank,unsigned char address,unsigned char *receive);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TagWriteSingleWord(HANDLE comm,unsigned char membank,unsigned char address,int data);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TagLock(HANDLE comm,unsigned char locktype);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int TagKill(HANDLE comm,unsigned char pa1,unsigned char pa2,unsigned char pa3,unsigned char pa4);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ResetReader(HANDLE comm);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int QueryReaderSingleParameter(HANDLE comm,unsigned char msb,unsigned char lsb,unsigned char *receive);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int QueryReaderMultiParameter(HANDLE comm,unsigned char length,unsigned char msb,unsigned char lsb,unsigned char *receive);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetReaderSignleParameter(HANDLE comm,unsigned char msb,unsigned char lsb,unsigned char data);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetReaderMultiParameter(HANDLE comm,unsigned char length,unsigned char msb,unsigned char lsb,unsigned char *write_data);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ReadMultiTag(HANDLE comm,unsigned char *count,unsigned char *id_buffer);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AfreshIdentifyTag(HANDLE comm);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AfreshGetData(HANDLE comm,unsigned char *count,unsigned char *data);
```

According to the documentation, it only supports Visual C++, VB, C++ Builder and Delphi. I'm writing the program in V C++. So the idea is that I open the communication with the `OpenComm` (it works), but after that if I use `ReadSoftwareVersion` or `ResetReader` it does not work. They provided a Demo software where I can select the port (COM1-9) and the baud rate (I used 9600) and then connect.

Surprisingly the it works just fine. If I disconnect with the demo software and connect with my own software using the provided functions, they suddenly work. I assume it has something to do with the baud rate, because none of the provided functions have that option, and they don't mention it in the sdk documentation either, but it is present in the demo app.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>

// SDK header file
#include "EPCDemoDll.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    HANDLE comm;
    char port[5] = "COM3";
    OpenComm(&comm, port);

    int flag = ResetReader(comm);
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "reset OK" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "reset ERROR" << endl;
    }

    CloseComm(comm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can set the COM speed using winapi function `SetCommState()` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate). No need for a specific function. But I think that an initialization call is needed before to open the connection (or just after).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I was able to get it working by adding this:

```
DCB comm_data;
if (GetCommState(comm, &comm_data) != 0) {
   comm_data.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
   comm_data.ByteSize = 8;
   comm_data.Parity = NOPARITY;
   comm_data.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
   if (SetCommState(comm, &comm_data) != 0)
      return 0;
   return 1;
}
```